# Program reading CPU temperature incorrectly when put on new computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, openhardwaremonitor

I am trying to add a feature to an existing program that would display the current CPU core temperature using the [Open Hardware Monitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/downloads/).  I have it working properly on my personal computer where it displays the temperature on a tool strip status label and refreshes on a timer. However, when I copy everything over to a new PC and test run the program the temperatures it returns are always coming back roughly 25 degrees higher than what the Monitor shows. If anyone has any ideas as to why it would read correctly on one computer but not another I would appreciate it as I'm stumped...

Here are the Monitor Temps and what my program is displaying on my PC both matched up.

[Open Hardware Monitor temperatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2HMu.png)

[Temperature displayed in program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap3LC.png)

Now these are the temperatures displayed on the new PC that would be shipped out.

[New PC Open Hardware Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWugy.png)

[Program temperature display on New PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIJIc.png)

This is the code I am currently using to get the temps.

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    Dim cp As New Computer()
    cp.Open()
    cp.HDDEnabled = True
    cp.FanControllerEnabled = True
    cp.RAMEnabled = True
    cp.GPUEnabled = True
    cp.MainboardEnabled = True
    cp.CPUEnabled = True

    Dim Info As String = ""
    Timer3.Interval = 5000
    For i As Integer = 0 To cp.Hardware.Length - 1
        Dim hw = cp.Hardware(i)

        Select Case hw.HardwareType

            Case HardwareType.CPU

                ToolStripStatusLabel5.Text = "CPU" & vbCrLf
                For j = 0 To hw.Sensors.Length - 1
                    Dim sensor = hw.Sensors(j)
                    If cp.Hardware(i).Sensors(j).SensorType = SensorType.Temperature Then
                        ToolStripStatusLabel5.Text = sensor.Name & " - " & sensor.Value & vbCrLf
                    End If
                Next
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I could definitely be wrong but I dont think your question has anything to do with VB.Net or VisualStudio 2017. Those tags are for questions that center around the VB language/syntax and questions that center around, explicitly, functionality of visual studio 2017 respectively

Comment: I added them because I thought there might be something I could have left out of my code that would help with this since they're what I am using. Just trying to cover the bases, if that was wrong of me then I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the error in the code, here is [an example](http://www.lattepanda.com/topic-f11t3004.html) of using OpenHardwaremonitor and WMI to get the CPU temperature, maybe you can try it.

Comment: I've tried that method as well to the same effect. For some reason it works fine on my laptop but keeps reading off when I put it on the new computer.

Comment: Please check the follow link for another solution:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh-CN/17316912-e1cc-4640-ab40-504e8a9feb9b/cpu?forum=vbasiczhchs